# new brakes discs and pads at front making knocking sound

Tags: brakes

6m ago I had new front discs and break pads, since then have had a knocking when breaking when at slow speeds, sitting in traffic. It went back and they tightened up everything and adjusted springs in the brakes. Over the last few weeks it has intermittently restarted only at slow speeds such as when in traffic or parking the cars. Honda tell me it’s nothing to worry about, and normal!, however this doesn’t sit well with me, sound like in back of car when I’m in the car but was front passenger wheel last time so could be the same. No ones listened from outside this time

Comment: Are you feeling a pulsing or pulling in the steering wheel? If not, might want to think about the rear wheels. Does it sound like a clunk or more of a squeak? The first could be something like a bit of material from the shroud around the disk (just happened to me) while the second could just be the brakes bedding in.